# Need help with top nav

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

Basically I am setting up a music store for a client and on my main nav at the top I want to have the category 'genre' so that it doesn't actually have its own page, but still links to all of the genres and their pages instead. If you look at the picture I have included it says 'view all genre' but I don't want that link or page to exist. I still want it in the nav so that it drops down to the genres though.

[image]

How would I go about doing this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your theme directory then open `template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`
Then delete 64-68 line which is creating a `li > a` with view all link. So remove that.

Also you can add `li.view-all{display:none;}` on your css file. to remove this link.

Comment: Tried to vote but not enough rep yet. gonna try this!

Comment: Css didn't work, gonna try the html

Comment: OK. also please delete the cache.

Comment: The html worked, but now 'search settings' has appeard in a white box on my homepage? wtf

Comment: If this help then please vote

Comment: as i said, i tried to vote, but i don't have enough rep

Comment: No problem my friend.